# Glide Imgae loading is taking too much time in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, image-loading, imageurl

In my app I have implemented a recyclerview widget to show userimage, name and company name. I have stored the text information into Realm DB, and those information are showing just after starting the app. But for image loading i am using Glide image library. But the problem is the image are not loading just after the button click as long as I do not go throug the whole recyclerview. So just after clicking the recyclerview if I see only first 10 row, it is loading first images one after one. And then when I go back to other page and if the internet connection is not there, the other images are not loading. The Image field is empty. Is there any way to load image faster with glide.

My code in adapter class

```
public class MyColleaguesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueHolder>{

    public static String TAG = MyColleaguesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    protected RequestManager glideManager; //make glideManager keeping
    private List<MyColleagueModel> myColleague;


    private Context context;

    public interface ColleagueListListener {
    }

    public MyColleaguesAdapter(List<MyColleagueModel> colleagues,Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        myColleague = colleagues;
        glideManager = Glide.with(context);
    }


    // create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ColleagueHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate( R.layout.colleage_row,parent,false);
        return new ColleagueHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ColleagueHolder holder, int position) {
        app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        final MyColleagueModel currentColleague = myColleague.get(position);

        holder.colleagueName.setText(currentColleague.getName());
        holder.companyName.setText(currentColleague.getCompany());
        holder.jobTitle.setText(currentColleague.getTitle());

        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Constant.color);



         Glide.with( holder.itemView.getContext() )
                    .load( Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() 
  )
                    .thumbnail( 0.5f )
                    .override( 200, 200 )
                    .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
                    .into( holder.colleaguePicture );


        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailMyColleague.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("IMAGE_URL",Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail());

                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myColleague.size();
    }

    public class ColleagueHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public CardView cardView;
        public ImageView colleaguePicture;
        public TextView colleagueName;
        public TextView  companyName;
        public TextView  jobTitle;

        public ColleagueHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            colleaguePicture= itemView.findViewById(R.id.colleague_picture);
            colleagueName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.colleague_name);
            companyName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.company_name);
            jobTitle= itemView.findViewById(R.id.job_title);
            cardView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_user);

        }
    }
```

In main Activity

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyColleaguesAdapter adapter;
private List<MyColleagueModel> myColleagueList = new ArrayList<>();
private ColleagueController mController;
private ColleagueResApiManager mApiManager;

private Realm colleagueRealm;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);
    CookieHandler.setDefault( cookieManager );

     colleagueConfigViews();

}

public void colleagueConfigViews() {
    recyclerView = this.findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyColleaguesPage.this));
    recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());

    colleagueRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    RealmResults<MyColleagueModel> results = colleagueRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).findAll( );

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

        myColleagueList.add(results.get(i));
    }
    adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter(myColleagueList,getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: it will take time to load image from url you can use **Placeholder** to display image while loading

Comment: try .override( 100, 100 )

Comment: @NileshRathod How can I use place holder here. is there any benefit of using this, Sorry I am new in android developing

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I tried earlier in this way but the image image quality is very llow then

Comment: @tamrezh21 using place holder you can display a image while your image loading from url check [my below ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212688/7666442)

Comment: @tamrezh21 refer second option from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45938483/5148289)

Comment: use universal image loader instead-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43224265/7230266

Comment: Why are you using `Glide.with( holder.itemView.getContext() );` twice ?

Comment: Are you shure that your performance problem comes from glide-imgae-loading? you have implemented a kind of arrayAdapter which is completely loaded in `colleagueConfigViews()`. how many items do you get by `colleagueRealm.where(...)` ? if you have to load 300 items or more a cursoradapter may be much faster. the cursorloader loads only visible items (on demand) while your array implementation always load all

Comment: I have implement MyColleaguesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyColleaguesAdapter.ColleagueHolder> for mapping the item of recyclerview. Hence I am very new android developing. I have almost 250 items in Colleague Realm. the data is sloading. but the image is not loading as long as I do not go throug the entire recyclerview.  What is cursor loader . Could you please explain

Answer (score 1):

as per [my above comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212596/glide-imgae-loading-is-taking-too-much-time-in-recyclerview-android#comment79388143_46212596) Glide take time to load image from url you can use **Placeholder** to display image while loading

```
Glide.with( holder.itemView.getContext() )
                .load( Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() )
                .thumbnail( 0.5f )
                .override( 200, 200 )
                 .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
                .into( holder.colleaguePicture );
```

Comment: how can I declare R.drawable.ic_placeholder in drawable folder

Comment: @tamrezh21 just add a sample image you want to display in your **res/drawable** folder than access it via **R.id.yourImageName**

Comment: Not solved the problem. still having the same problem

Comment: @tamrezh21 **Glide take time to load image from url**

Comment: could you please tell me what process would be faster to load image from url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try below. 
I'm using below code in my app. There is no speed issue..

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColleagueHolder > {    

   protected RequestManager glideManager; //make glideManager keeping

   protected MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context ....Activity or Fragment) {
       mContext = context;
       glideManager = Glide.with((Fragment or Activity) object);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ColleagueHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.colleagueName.setText(currentColleague.getName());
      holder.companyName.setText(currentColleague.getCompany());
      holder.jobTitle.setText(currentColleague.getTitle());
      holder.colleaguePicture.setImageResource( R.drawable.profile_image );

      glideManager
            .load(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail() )
            .placeholder(R.drawable.myholder)
            .fitCenter()
            .override(200, 200)
            .into(holder.colleaguePicture);

     holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailMyColleague.class);
              i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              i.putExtra("IMAGE_URL",Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL + currentColleague.getMail());
              .....
              context.startActivity(i);
    }
});
   }
}
```

Comment: Where can i write the RequestManager and MyRecyclerAdapater method, in main activity. Could you please explain more

Comment: I have updated my code based on yours, I have activity there. Could you please check and tell me and how can I call adapter in main activity also , what else shall i do, sorry I am very new i android developing

Comment: I saw your updated source. And I don't think that there is no issue about using recyclerView adapter.  So I want you to check 1. data loading time 2. make data small (if data row is 2000, make data 20)  If data loading is the problem, you have to make your loading data asynchronously(like using thread or AsyncTask or relam's async data loading)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(URL)
         .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

Comment: please add some more information about your answer .